# NestJs DTO: Default value of string in dto with min length 3

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator, class-transformer

I have to create a DTO that contains a field `searchTerm`. If this value is provided from the client then minimum length must be 3 otherwise, I should have an empty string i.e. `searchTerm = '';`. Is there any way I can achieve this in DTO file using class-validator and/or class-transformer package/s?

This is what I have achieved so far. It is working fine if received a value from the client but otherwise `searchTerm` must be equal to that value, if passed and length > 3, else should be an empty string.

```
@ApiPropertyOptional({default: ''})
@IsString()
@IsOptional()
@Type(() => String)
@MinLength(3)
searchTerm: string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [conditional validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) by adding `@validateIf(o => o.searchTerm)` before the other decorators. This checks if the `searchTerm` is provided, performs the other validations otherwise skips.

Comment: Thanks Soroush, It worked exactly as expected.